# I just want to call some loop when give the condition. but it was error

Tags: javascript

```
var game1 = prompt("Welcome to FuzzBUzz", "Let's try now GO");
for (var i= 1; i<21; i++){
    if(i / 3){
        console.log("Fizz");
        }
    else if (i/ 5){
        console.log("Buzz");
        }
    else if ((i / 3) && (i / 5)){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
    else{
        console.log("choose what you want");
        }
};
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are not conditional.  You are just dividing i by a number.  If you want to check if it's divisible, use the modulus and check for 0.

```
if(i%3 == 0){ //if i can be divided evenly by 3, then do something
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in if statements need to evaluate to a result which tells the if statement whether or not to execute the block; if the condition holds true the block is executed and vice versa.  Change your condition statements to be statements which can be evaluated using comparison operators like: ==, !=, >, >= and you will be successful.

Comment: `if` statements do not need `true` or `false` explicitly.

Comment: Not explicitly, but they do need to evaluate to a go/no go condition....time for an edit.